# Как сделать новую строчку без br?

Tags: css, css3

В параграфе поставил br для новой строки. Но при отдалении экрана (ctrl - ),
br выходит за пределы родительского элемента, в ту позицию, где она была бы без br. Overflow: hidden не помогает.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с `div`:

```html
<div>Строчка 1</div>
<div>Строчка 2</div>
```

Вариант с `p`:

```html
<p>Строчка 1</p>
<p>Строчка 2</p>
```

Вариант с добавлением разделителя `hr`:

```css
hr {border: 0; height: 1px; background: none;}
```

```html
Строчка 1
<hr>
Строчка 2
```